# How can I test for a totally empty inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a custom Minecraft map in which I need to `/testfor` if a player has a totally empty inventory. I tried Googling but I didn't get any results. So if anyone can help me by providing suitable `/testfor` command it would be very very helpful.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Thx for ur opinion. Im a noob to this stack exchange world so i dont know some stuffs

Comment: And it's in your best interest to show that you won't waste ours or other's time. You are free to ask questions all you like, but we do expect you to display some effort. You'll get a better response when you do.

Comment: I can't comment more without knowing why you want to test for this, but make sure your design can't be exploited by throwing everything down, getting whatever you're giving them for having nothing, and then picking their stuff back up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this command:

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[]}
```

I tried this and it seems to work, but if you encounter any problems, please comment and I will look into it.

Comment: This will indeed work; testing for an empty list tag will check if the target's list is also empty. As the inverse, checking for the existence of a compound will return if the player had any items at all (`/testfor @a {Inventory:[{}]}`).

Comment: ash4funs i tried your code but it isn't working it say players does not meet the data tag

Comment: @KartikPillai Are you certain that your inventory is empty? You have no armor or anything else?

Comment: Im 100% sure that there is no items including armor in my inventory

Comment: try swapping the `@a` for `@p`

Comment: @KartikPillai Are you on the latest version?

Comment: Ya 1.8.9 i have 1.9 but im making this map on 1.8.9

Comment: Sorry the code is working it was my fault thx sooo much @ash4fun

Comment: @KartikPillai: I don't understand why someone would make a map that uses any number of command blocks on 1.8.9, since 1.9 is so much better for that.  Seriously, if you're doing command block stuff, do it in 1.9!

Comment: @KartikPillai If you want, replace `@a` with anything from this section, depending on who you want to test this on: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Target_selector_variables

Answer (score 1):

## 1.13+ update

`/testfor` was superseded by `/execute if entity`. Therefore, the new command is as follows:

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[]}] run ...
```

If you want to include ender chest inventory, you can use:

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[],EnderItems:[]}] run ...
```